# CamelContext not picking up Spring annotated Routes

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have just started to use Camel in one of my projects. I am trying to configure Camel with Spring, but having issues doing that.
I don't want to use xml configuration but rather go with Spring based Annotations for configuring Routes and Processors.

My App is a stand alone Spring Application, which will be run as Jar.
To keep the app running, I've a empty scheduled method which runs every x min.

Below are the dependencies in my `build.gralde`

```
// Spring //
compile('org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.0.RC2')
compile('org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.0.RC2')
compile('org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.0.RC2')
compile('org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.0.0.RC2')
// Apache //
// Camel //
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.19.1')
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-spring:2.19.1')
```

snapshot of `beans.xml`

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

<camelContext id="aggregatorCamelContext" autoStartup="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <package>
            my.package.camel
        </package>        
</camelContext>
```

Sample `RouteBuilder`

```
@Component
public class SampleRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    MyClass myObject;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("file:filelist")
            .process(myObject)
            .to("file:processedList");
    }

}
```

To keep the app alive ( I know bit hacky, but suffices for now )

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class KeepitAlive {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000l)
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("KeepitAlive.run "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() );
    }
}
```

Main Class. I have tried both the methods, Initializing Spring context as well as Camel Main, but to no luck

```
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /*AbstractXmlApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/beans.xml");*/

        Main main = new Main();
        main.setApplicationContextUri("path/to/beans.xml");
        main.start();
    }

}
```

If I put my Route within camelContext declaration itself, it works absolutely fine,

```
    <route>
        <from uri="file:filelist"/>
        <to uri="file:processedlist"/>
    </route>
```

I've also looked into Camel Spring Integration [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/springintegration.html), but it also contains xml based configuration.
Could anybody please guide me in right direction.

Comment: Use the `run` method on the `Main` class if its from Apache Camel. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using Camel's own package scanning via

`<package>
            my.package.camel
        </package>`

You should use `<contextScan>` if you want Camel to find the Spring `@Component` Camel routes.

See the Camel spring documentation for more: http://camel.apache.org/spring.html

Comment: I tried with <contextScan> also, but Camel was not able to auto discover. I didn't try `run` method on `Main` though as you mentioned in the comment. It seem to work with `main.run()` method instead of `main.start()` with `RouteBuilder`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Camel is not officially supporting Spring 5.0.x. We have not even tried upgrading and testing on that version. This will come officially supported in a later Camel release when Spring 5 is GA and we get around to upgrading.

Comment: Got it. I was suspecting the same. Will see if I could step down the version.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out ultimately. Need to extend `SpringRouteBuilder` instead of `RouteBuiler` above in `SampleRoute` class.
Anybody struggling with issues, I suggest once go through `Camel in Action` book.
Somehow I missed it in the beginning which costed me lot of time figuring out trivial things that this book covers.